# Dashboard & Pubcenter confusion

Tags: windows-phone-8

I made a Windows Phone app, created a pubcenter account and made an ad unit.
I pasted the ApplicationId & AdUnitId in my code and published the app.

It's live now
http://www.windowsphone.com/nl-be/store/app/weird-funny-facts/6353f4b4-cc80-47be-bd79-bc5d834d0d8f?signin=true

Today I checked my dashboard and in my settings I saw this:
pubCenter Application ID
None
Ad units
None

Shouldn't the ID's be filled in? I tried editing my details, but I could only make new ad units from that point.. which I don't understand? Why would you upload your app, then make ad units, put these in your code, rebuild and reupload?

Won't the ads work without the information filled in? Can anyone enlighten me :)

screenshot:
[image: dashboard screenshot]

Comment: I downloaded your app and it shows ads alright.

Comment: Thank you for checking it venerik! I'm still confused about why the why of all this :)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your dashboard ?